# Microsoft Azure Backup Server TCP/UDP Ports to open

Tags: backup, firewall, azure, port

Planning to install Microsoft Azure Backup Server in our production environment which is firewall restricted, but I could not find any documents which specify the exact TCP/UDP port requirements.

What are the TCP/UDP ports that needs to be open for the ‘Microsoft Azure Backup Server’?

I can see some of the ports that are used by the ‘Microsoft Azure Backup Server’ in our development environment:

Process Name - Listening Ports:

- Cbengine.exe – TCP 6049
- DPMRA.exe – TCP 5718
- MSDPM.exe – TCP 49636, UDP 51379

Comment: Try to cut jitter, and tell only the most important parts. For example, your first sentence is absolutely unnecessary. People will more likely deal with your issue, if they can read&understand it fast. I removed your first sentence, and formatted the last part of your question

Comment: Check this Microsoft page for reference https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-ports/

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked in 2016 however we currently (July 2018) have an open Microsoft Premier ticket on this very issue as a backup job is failing. Here was response from Microsoft.

Per Microsoft what is required for Azure remote backups to work:

Please whitelist the following:

1. `www.msftncsi.com`
2. `*.microsoft.com`
3. `*.windowsazure.com`
4. `*.microsoftonline.com`
5. `*.windows.net`

Ports to open: `443` and `6049`

If IPs are required, latest downloadable public IP of Azure datacenters can be found here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

Answer (score -1):

Found the article **'Configure firewall settings for DPM'**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757794.aspx

It must be the same ports as Windows Azure Backup Server is based in DPM.